# How to make clang format not place comments?

Tags: c++, clang, clang-format

Every time I create a namespace or start a namespace block, clang-format adds a comment at the namespace closing. I don't want this. How do I disable it?

Example:

```
} // namespace geometry
```

My configuration:

```
BasedOnStyle: LLVM,
UseTab: Never,
IndentWidth: 2,
TabWidth: 2,
BreakBeforeBraces: Attach,
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: true,
IndentCaseLabels: false,
ColumnLimit: 0,
AccessModifierOffset: -2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

`FixNamespaceComments: false`

to your config.  This doesn’t affect short namespaces, which are controlled by `ShortNamespaceLines`.